# Why does QColor use 32-bit signed int to represent e.g. rgba values?

Tags: c++, qt, integer, implicit-conversion, qcolor

`QColor` can return rgba values of type `int` (32-bit signed integer). Why is that? The color values range from 0-255, don't they? Is there any situation where this might not be the case?

I'm considering to implicitly cast each of the rgba values returned by `QColor.red()/green()/blue()/alpha()` to `quint8`. It seems to work but I don't know if this will lead to problems in some cases. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, color channels on an 8-bit display have that range. But what about other bit depths, HDR etc.

Comment: `QColor` has four components - 8 bits each. To store them together you need 32 bits, not 8. If you cast the value to 8 bit number, you will loose the information.

Comment: @paddy That makes sense. Thank you! I guess then as long as I make sure my `QColor` values are always in the range 0-255, it's no problem. I'm relying on 8-bit color representation per channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [`QColor::rgba()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#rgba) which returns a [`QRgb`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef).

`QRgb` is an alias to unsigned int. In these 32 bits all fours channels are encoded as `#AARRGGBB`, 8 bits each one (0-255, as you mentioned). So, a color like alpha=32, red=255, blue=127, green=0 would be `0x20FF7F00` (`553615104` in decimal).

Now, regarding your question about casting to `quint8`, there should be no problem since each channel is guaranteed to be in the range 0..255 ([reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#integer-vs-floating-point-precision)). In general, Qt usually uses `int` as a general integer and do not pay too much attention to the width of the data type, unless in some specific situations (like when it is necessary for a given memory access, for example). So, do not worry about that.

Now, if these operations are done frequently in a high performance context, think about retrieving the 32 bits once using `QColor::rgba` and then extract the components from it. You can access the individual channels using bitwise operations, or through the convenience functions [`qAlpha`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qAlpha), [`qRed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qRed), [`qBlue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qBlue) and [`qGreen`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#qGreen).

For completeness, just to mention that the sibbling [`QColor::rgb`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#rgb) method returns the same structure but the alpha channel is opaque (0xFF). You also have [`QColor::rgba64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html#rgba64), which returns a [`QRgba64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrgba64.html#details). It uses 16 bits per channel, for higher precision. You have the 64 bits equivalents to `qAlpha`, etc, as `qAlpha64` and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the extra information!